# Haven't heard back from the recruiter after Skype interview. What's a good way to word my enquiry?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

I had a Skype interview on a Friday(last week) and the interview was for a job abroad. The interview went fine fortunately I could answer most questions correctly. In the end I discussed how the process goes ahead if they are ready to go ahead with me. I was told by the employer that they normally have a trial day and have the person come to the office meet colleagues and one more interview, he asked if I can manage it? I said YES then he ended the call by saying that he would get back to me by Mid of next week for further steps.

I haven't heard back from them as yet and Thursday is also almost past now. Now I wish to follow but mean I am confused in what way should I word it and send it across in a mail.

Comment: Hi Anirudh and welcome to [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com)! Unfortunately, the question you asked is very similar to [Great interview - hiring manager never followed up, should I follow up with a call?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/14654) and is likely to be closed as a [duplicate](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates). If that question does not address your specific scenario, please [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/32333/edit) your question and explain how your situation is different. I hope to see you around! :D

Comment: hey Matt! Thanks for the welcome but as I read that question there seems to be a different motive that the asker wants to accomplish when he says "Is it appropriate to call?" I am not confused about that I am sure to follow up just was running out a courteous way to express myself..hence this is not a duplicate.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Comment: @Anirudh - Do the answers to that question help?  What is missing from them that you are wanting to know?  Edit that information into your question and it will progbably get reopened.

Answer (score 4):

It is perfectly fair to say, "[Name of recipient], I'm still interested in [Name of position]. I wanted to touch base with you and see where things stand" or similar (don't copy that word for word, you need to ask the same in whatever manner you'd ask)

At this point though, they just slipped past the time they told you they'd answer by, it's perfectly fair, even advisable to give them a little reminder you're out there waiting. There are plenty of fair reasons they are a tad late. Even if they found someone else for the role the call back could be you in favor if that person doesn't work out, or future hiring.

Comment: @RualStorage probably what I was looking for..

Answer (score 2):

While what RualStorge says is good wording, but I'd like to point out that less than 2 days after when he said he'd call is not late at all.  Businesses can take a long time to get back, for all sorts of reasons, most of which have nothing to do with you.  You should only check in once and then move on, so don't waste that by checking in too early.

You could send a followup email (see [Should a thank you letter be sent after an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19196/should-a-thank-you-letter-be-sent-after-an-interview)) and ask what the next steps will be, if you haven't already.  But read [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manger-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-po) first too.

Comment: Yep once is typically a plus in my book when hiring, more than once is a negative. (unless I revise the date at which point you should only call once a day or two after that point) if I revise the date again... well that's likely a hint to move on.

Comment: So what should be the ideal time to contact him in my case as per you? @thursdaysgeek

Comment: Give them at least through the end of the week, so sometime next week would be fine.  All sorts of things can come up to cause delays, from other work they are doing, other people they need to talk to being out, to personal emergencies.  Give them enough time that they don't feel rushed.  By the way, if they want to hire you, they won't forget that.  It just can take time.