# Tricky Situation in Hiring Process

Tags: interviewing, follow-up

So this is a follow up question to [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32333/havent-heard-back-from-the-recruiter-after-skype-interview-whats-a-good-way-t/32339#32339)

As the previous one got marked as duplicate hence asking a new question.

A week after the interview I sent a mail to the employer asking him about how things stand now, to which he said "Their HR deptt. would contact me for scheduling of the next round"

I replied back with a Thank you email on this now after this almost 13 days are past and I haven't heard back from the HR yet.

**Interesting Part**:
Well as it happened in the interview and in mail threads before they began the interview process at all It seemed they were thinking I was maybe a little over qualified for the position, so they took confirmation from my side twice about my comfort level with the position offered I said I totally had no qualms about it whatsoever as the position was like little more than 80% match of my skill and experience.

Now a couple of days back I saw another job posting from the same employer which is even closer match to my skill-set and experience say 90% this time.

**Now I am in confusion whether I should apply to this position?** or **I should just check with the employer once again about my status of candidature** for the next round as it seems I might be in the waiting list, In case I ask them what would be ideal ways to word it I am wondering?

Comment: Are you sure the new job posting is for a different position than the one you applied for? Maybe the company only refined the job description to get more applications?

Comment: Well it was changed from software test engineer to software test automation engineer but anyhow do you think it's worth asking for an update from the employer/

Comment: Yes, I would wait another day and then ask them for an update (then it will be two weeks since your last E-Mail). Asking will not damage your chances, as it shows your interest. Maybe they already have decided against you. In this case it's good for you to know so you don't have to bother about this any more.

Answer (score 3):

The worst that can happen is that they've decided you weren't right for the job and have decided to re-advertise, so be honest and straightforward.

Go back to them and say:

"I see that you've advertised job Y, which is similar to the job I applied for, job X.  If this is a separate job, I believe that I'm qualified to do either, so would like to be considered for job Y.

If this is the same job, I'm obviously still interested but I will understand if you think I'm not the right fit for your organisation.

Whatever the cause, I am still very keen to work for your company and am looking forward to hearing back from you."

Something like that.  The key things are to emphasise that you still want to work for them, that you're professional enough to handle rejection and that you're forthright enough to take positive steps to get things sorted.

Good luck!